# Android : Getting a Bitmap from a url connection (graph.facebook.com) that redirects to another url

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, bitmap, redirect

I have done everything to get a url where i can get the profile pic of a facebook user.

The only problem left now is to get that image into a bitmap object.

Since,  http://graph.facebook.com now redirects the connection first (as we can see in the url) to https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/... (something like this).

So, i wanted to ask as to how can i get the bitmap from the url : http://graph.facebook.com/... 
that redirects to https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/...

Comment: Shouldn't you add a `facebook` tag too?

Comment: @hiphopdroid I thought that making it general would be more appropriate. Because url redirection is not only in this case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are right in saying that  http://graph.facebook.com redirects the connection first (as we can see in the url) to https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/, but-

> auto redirection works automatically when original and redirected protocols are same.

So, if you try to load images from **https** instead of http : "https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture"; since image's url is "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/....", `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` shall work again to get you the bitmap.

Here's the code-

```
URL imgUrl = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/picture?type=large");
InputStream in = (InputStream) imgUrl.getContent();
Bitmap  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
```

Hope that helps. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but i was really busy in other work that i wasnt able to check this question again.

I havent tried out your code yet (i really sorry if it bothered you).

I will get back to you as soon as i try your code.

Comment: Sorry, for replying late again but i didnt even had time to sleep properly for the last few days.

Comment: I tried your method and it works without any problems. Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: @Sahil Mittal I get next error: "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException". Have you put this code in an AsyncTask? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Update : The method given by Sahil Mittal works absolutely fine and i would definitely ask you guys to use his method.**

As for the method I used in the meantime you can read this answer.

<strike>I dont know whether the method given by Sahil Mittal works or not.</strike>

I havent tried that but i used another code segment which seems to work for me.

But i will get back whether it works or not as soon as i try it.

```
Bitmap getUserBitmap(String username){


        HttpGet httpRequest = null;

        Bitmap userbmp = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/" + username + "/picture?type=small");

            httpRequest = new HttpGet(url.toURI());

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);

            InputStream instream = bufHttpEntity.getContent();

            userbmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(instream);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        userbmp = getRoundedShape(userbmp); // function call to make the image round
        return (userbmp);
    }
```