# Get user profile image Android facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

How can i show the fecebook user profile image on Android?

I have been searching on the web and the answer seems to be to add the `https` to the `URL`, but i already set it and i can't get the image, instead of that, i get an interrogation mark:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    URL imageURL = null;
    try {
        imageURL = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + userID + "/picture?width=" + width +"&height=" + width);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        bitmap = getCroppedBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageURL.openConnection().getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

A few months ago i could show the profile image with any problem, but now i got this... any idead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For new SDK of facebook try this one :

```
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());

                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,picture");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

```
loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile, email, user_birthday, user_friends"));
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    accessToken,
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(
                                JSONObject object,
                                GraphResponse response) {
                            try {

                                String userID = (String) object.get("id");
                                String userName = (String) object.get("name");

                                Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load("https://graph.facebook.com/" + userID+ "/picture?type=large").into(imageView);
                                //Bitmap b = (Bitmap) object.get("picture");
                                tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                                tv.setText("Hello" + " " + userName);
                                Log.d("o/p", "name");
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,birthday,picture");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }
```

Try this.

Comment: You will also need to download a Picasso Library which can be found [here](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: works, but you actually need to also specify the "email" field in the parameters object if you want to grab it from the JSON later like you do with the name and ID

Answer (score 3):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22929788/2497859).

```
imageURL = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + userID + "/picture?width=" + width +"&height=" + height);
InputStream inputStream = (InputStream) imageURL.getContent();
bitmap = getCroppedBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream));
```

Comment: I get next error: "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException". Have you put this code in an AsyncTask? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right URL:

```
URL MyProfilePicURL = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?type=normal&method=GET&access_token="+ Access_token );
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ImageView widget to display the profile picture.

```
imageURL = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + userID + "/picture?width=" + width +"&height=" + height);
Picasso.with(this.context).load(imageUrl.toString()).fit().into(imageView);
```

To import Picasso put the below line in the `dependencies` section of `build.gradle` file in your app.

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I do it in my app:

```
Profile currentProfile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
Uri profilePictureUri = currentProfile.getProfilePictureUri(width, height);
// download the image or set it to a view
downloadUserProfilePicture(profilePictureUri.toString());
```